# Use only one checkbox from two

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a form that has two checkboxes, now you can click the checkbox on both

The question is, is it possible to make it so that there is only one choice? For example, clicked on the first one, it turned on, clicked on the second one, the first turned off, the second turned on. It should also be possible to uncheck the box at any time. I know that I can use the radio type, but I need only checkboxes

```css
.call-form-item {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

input {
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      background-color: #EEF0F7;
      margin-right: 10px;
}

.input-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
}

label {
      color: #808694;
      font-family: Montserrat;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      letter-spacing: 0;
      line-height: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:focus {
      outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    input[type=checkbox] {
      background-color: #EEF0F7;
      border-radius: 2px;
      appearance: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      width: 17px;
      height: 17px;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked {
      background-color: #808694;
      background: #808694 url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwAKAIABAP////3cnSH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAALAAoAAAIUjH+AC73WHIsw0UCjglraO20PNhYAOw==") 3px 3px no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contacts-call-form">
    <form class="js-form" action="{{ route('send-contacts-call') }}">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="call-form-item">
                <label for="name">Name *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input class="js-form-call-name" id="name" type="text" name="name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="call-form-item">
                <label for="email">Email *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input class="js-form-call-email" id="email" type="email" name="email">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="call-form-item">
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input class="js-form-call-check1" id="check1" name="check1" type="checkbox"><label>Check 1</label>
                    <input class="js-form-call-check2" id="check2" name="check2" type="checkbox"><label>Check 2</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know about the disabled attribute? It seems to be precisely what you are looking for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

Comment: @mrmonsieur yes, but how can I use it in my example, write a script?

Comment: yes, do you know javascript well? I could write an answer with more detail.

Comment: @mrmonsieur not really, if you can tell me more please

Comment: @mrmonsieur sorry, I asked the question a little wrong, they should not become unclickable, but simply switch like radio buttons, turn on the first one, turn off the second one and so on

Comment: If my logic is right, the answer I posted lets you uncheck all boxes again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script would loo something like this. I didn't test this so there might be misspellings causing errors and such.

```
// get first checkbox element
let box1 = document.getElementByID( "check1" );

// get second checkbox element
let box2 = document.getElementByID( "check2" );

// add events that fires when boxes are checked
box1.addEventListener( "change", function() {

  // see if the other box is already checked
  if ( box2.checked ) {

    // if so, uncheck it
    box2.checked = false;
  }
});
box2.addEventListener( "change", function() {
  if ( box1.checked ) {
    box1.checked = false;
  }
});
```

But you can also just use radio buttons and invoke a hidden reset button when you click a checked radio button I think.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version that will work with any number of checkboxes.

```js
const inps=document.querySelectorAll(".input-wrapper input");
inps.forEach(e=>e.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
  inps.forEach(c=>{if(c!==e) c.checked=false})
}))
```

```css
.call-form-item {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

input {
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      background-color: #EEF0F7;
      margin-right: 10px;
}

.input-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
}

label {
      color: #808694;
      font-family: Montserrat;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      letter-spacing: 0;
      line-height: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:focus {
      outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    input[type=checkbox] {
      background-color: #EEF0F7;
      border-radius: 2px;
      appearance: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      width: 17px;
      height: 17px;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked {
      background-color: #808694;
      background: #808694 url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwAKAIABAP////3cnSH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAALAAoAAAIUjH+AC73WHIsw0UCjglraO20PNhYAOw==") 3px 3px no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<div class="contacts-call-form">
    <form class="js-form" action="{{ route('send-contacts-call') }}">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="call-form-item">
                <label for="name">Name *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input class="js-form-call-name" id="name" type="text" name="name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="call-form-item">
                <label for="email">Email *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input class="js-form-call-email" id="email" type="email" name="email">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="call-form-item">
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input class="js-form-call-check1" id="check1" name="check1" type="checkbox"><label>Check 1</label>
                    <input class="js-form-call-check2" id="check2" name="check2" type="checkbox"><label>Check 2</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is an alternative, using radio buttons:

```js
const inps=document.querySelectorAll(".input-wrapper input");
inps.forEach(e=>e.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
  e.checked=e!==inps.last;
  inps.last=e.checked?e:null
}))
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <label><input name="radio" value="1" type="radio">Check 1</label>
  <label><input name="radio" value="2" type="radio">Check 2</label>
  <label><input name="radio" value="3" type="radio">Check 3</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution:
HTML:

```
<section> 
 <label><input type="checkbox" value="CBox 1"> CBox 1</label> 
 <label><input type="checkbox" value="CBox 2"> CBox 2</label> 
 <label><input type="checkbox" value="CBox 3"> CBox 3</label> 
 <label><input type="checkbox" value="CBox 4"> CBox 4</label> 
 <label><input type="checkbox" value="CBox 5"> CBox 5</label> 
</section>
<p> Checkbox acts like a radio button, but can be reset </p>
```

Javascript:

```
 const sel = document.querySelectorAll('section input[type="checkbox"]');
 for (el of sel) {
   el.addEventListener('click',
     function(e) { sel.forEach( (x) => { if (e.currentTarget != x) x.checked = false; } ); }
   );
 };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScript / jQuery for it. If `check1` is active, just disable `check2`.

See [change event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) and [disabled](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/)